# How do I allow FTP on SBS 2003

Tags: ftp, windows-sbs-2003

I've been asked to find out why a server cannot connect to our Data Distribution server via FTP (standard port 21).

The problem server is SBS 2003.  I've port forwarded FTP in their Gateway/Firewall (even though this server is not a FTP server itself).

Other servers/computers from our various offices can access our Distribution server fine...

Where do I start troubleshooting this?

Comment: [You should start by getting a migration plan in place to get off that aging hulk.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2013/09/25/information-about-sbs-2003-product-support-lifecycle.aspx)  Personally, I'd backup the data and accidentally set the server on fire, but a planned migration is probably the smarter idea.

Comment: Nevermind!  I found what was wrong.  Their pozy firewall on their gateway had FTP disabled in the "Advanced Firewall" settings page.  Damn ISP configured ADSL2+ modems...

Comment: The modem is a Thompson 2701HGV-W Gateway if anyone else has a similar problem.